# tiktok api get video url from post, video not showing

Tags: api, web-scraping, tiktok

I am using this tiktok API `https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/video/userId/videoId` and sample usage is https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/video/@beary730/6976969595781434626

it is returning the json below, but all the urls there are not showing the actual video url that plays. it just shows a greyed out player but no content.

the videourl of that post is [this](https://v16.tiktokcdn.com/952f3437ce28a4d57766c54c90963120/60d5cbcb/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037/1fba13a569b4467c8bd03d7a410b27e2/?a=1180&br=1154&bt=577&cd=0%7C0%7C1&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=3&ds=3&er=&l=202106250627350101152280760D1C6375&lr=tiktok&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M3A4OXU7aWxsNjMzODgzNEApNWdlOTdlOzs1N2dlZzRpZGdkLS5qXzEwbTZgLS1kLy1zc2MzMS80LmEuYl8tMl5eYWA6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=)

but the return (videoUrl) from json below is [this](https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037/1fba13a569b4467c8bd03d7a410b27e2/?a=1988&br=1154&bt=577&cd=0%7C0%7C1&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=3&ds=3&er=&expire=1624624896&l=202106250641170101902090884B1619CF&lr=tiktok&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M3A4OXU7aWxsNjMzODgzNEApNWdlOTdlOzs1N2dlZzRpZGdkLS5qXzEwbTZgLS1kLy1zc2MzMS80LmEuYl8tMl5eYWA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=ad9c22b5fb881a62dc0b94e7e095f8a0&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=)

This used to work but not anymore. How do I scrape the actual video url so I can embed it in a video player in our html page. What api should I use?

```
   {"seoProps":{"pageId":"6976969595781434626","pageType":0,"predictedLanguage":"en","metaParams":{"title":"Boys true or nah? | with Music original sound  - blueberry","keywords":"blueberry,beary730,TikTok, ティックトック, tik tok, tick tock, tic tok, tic toc, tictok, тик ток, ticktock","description":"blueberry (@beary730) has created a short video on TikTok with music original sound - blueberry. | Boys true or nah?","canonicalHref":"https://www.tiktok.com/@beary730/video/6976969595781434626","robotsContent":"index, follow","applicableDevice":"pc, mobile"},"videoObject":{},"jsonldList":[["VideoObject",{}],["BreadcrumbList",{}]]},"$language":"en","statusCode":0,"statusMsg":"","itemInfo":{"itemStruct":{"id":"6976969595781434626","desc":"Boys true or nah?","createTime":1624452324,"scheduleTime":0,"video":{"id":"6976969595781434626","height":1024,"width":576,"duration":20,"ratio":"720p","cover":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-alisg-p-0037/478261e212f4462bb320decf7d75842a?x-expires=1624629600&x-signature=4dL4QF%2FRORT95%2BbGGggPZ1vDK4A%3D","originCover":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-alisg-p-0037/ac1eb481ca9e4ce9b10d507e940e0928_1624452326?x-expires=1624629600&x-signature=vM1gkbIzm%2FrsPWMLlD2UoBdpCBE%3D","dynamicCover":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-alisg-p-0037/a68e82de8ea64978919ab6ee85ec90ce_1624452327?x-expires=1624629600&x-signature=Yf%2FMkbNj2MHPeG4hxZoqgnewLQ4%3D","playAddr":"https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037/1fba13a569b4467c8bd03d7a410b27e2/?a=1988&br=1154&bt=577&cd=0%7C0%7C1&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=3&ds=3&er=&expire=1624629740&l=202106250802010101152290731B032B28&lr=tiktok&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M3A4OXU7aWxsNjMzODgzNEApNWdlOTdlOzs1N2dlZzRpZGdkLS5qXzEwbTZgLS1kLy1zc2MzMS80LmEuYl8tMl5eYWA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=b8ca3031e60f752d0dc6ca1b8581daba&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=","downloadAddr":"https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037/1fba13a569b4467c8bd03d7a410b27e2/?a=1988&br=1154&bt=577&cd=0%7C0%7C1&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=3&ds=3&er=&expire=1624629740&l=202106250802010101152290731B032B28&lr=tiktok&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M3A4OXU7aWxsNjMzODgzNEApNWdlOTdlOzs1N2dlZzRpZGdkLS5qXzEwbTZgLS1kLy1zc2MzMS80LmEuYl8tMl5eYWA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=b8ca3031e60f752d0dc6ca1b8581daba&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=","shareCover":["","https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/tos-alisg-p-0037/ac1eb481ca9e4ce9b10d507e940e0928_1624452326~tplv-tiktok-play.jpeg?x-expires=1624629600&x-signature=wgto7OEbdMr6o28tJAlOGMmlSug%3D","https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/tos-alisg-p-0037/ac1eb481ca9e4ce9b10d507e940e0928_1624452326~tplv-tiktokx-share-play.jpeg?x-expires=1624629600&x-signature=f3YyHXYponL%2ByVlYjAjubskbhy8%3D"],"reflowCover":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-alisg-p-0037/478261e212f4462bb320decf7d75842a?x-expires=1624629600&x-signature=4dL4QF%2FRORT95%2BbGGggPZ1vDK4A%3D","bitrate":591166,"encodedType":"normal","format":"mp4","videoQuality":"normal","encodeUserTag":""},"author":{"id":"6964021718777185281","shortId":"0","uniqueId":"beary730","nickname":"blueberry","avatarLarger":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/1080x1080/tos-alisg-avt-0068/4ccc0bc773116840e424d5e4d45fb2e8.jpeg?x-expires=1624694400&x-signature=Iw5hiQ8ZmsjgebJM3pZGs5znDA0%3D","avatarMedium":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/720x720/tos-alisg-avt-0068/4ccc0bc773116840e424d5e4d45fb2e8.jpeg?x-expires=1624694400&x-signature=K38vJ6jc%2BSU3zkABKWdea8DvpU4%3D","avatarThumb":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/100x100/tos-alisg-avt-0068/4ccc0bc773116840e424d5e4d45fb2e8.jpeg?x-expires=1624694400&x-signature=J07i634gMXmF0BVBJRwOROhUJbo%3D","signature":"BLM\n\nI'M SO SORRY GUYS IF I CAN'T FOLLOW BACK Y'ALL","createTime":1621437798,"verified":false,"secUid":"MS4wLjABAAAAypC_aQxYhCkEfTtrR3y3WtLZnLSvgjHo9cjahmYG-9Kt1HZd4OT8zLHt3O47K50H","ftc":false,"relation":0,"openFavorite":false,"commentSetting":0,"duetSetting":3,"stitchSetting":3,"privateAccount":false,"secret":false,"isADVirtual":false,"roomId":""},"music":{"id":"6976969486352124674","title":"original sound - blueberry","playUrl":"https://sf16-ies-music-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tiktok-obj/6976969478353537794.mp3","coverLarge":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/1080x1080/tos-alisg-avt-0068/4ccc0bc773116840e424d5e4d45fb2e8.jpeg?x-expires=1624694400&x-signature=Iw5hiQ8ZmsjgebJM3pZGs5znDA0%3D","coverMedium":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/720x720/tos-alisg-avt-0068/4ccc0bc773116840e424d5e4d45fb2e8.jpeg?x-expires=1624694400&x-signature=K38vJ6jc%2BSU3zkABKWdea8DvpU4%3D","coverThumb":"https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/aweme/100x100/tos-alisg-avt-0068/4ccc0bc773116840e424d5e4d45fb2e8.jpeg?x-expires=1624694400&x-signature=J07i634gMXmF0BVBJRwOROhUJbo%3D","authorName":"blueberry","original":true,"duration":19,"album":"","scheduleSearchTime":0},"challenges":[],"stats":{"diggCount":406500,"shareCount":20300,"commentCount":21000,"playCount":2100000},"isActivityItem":false,"duetInfo":{"duetFromId":"0"},"warnInfo":[],"originalItem":false,"officalItem":false,"textExtra":[],"secret":false,"forFriend":false,"digged":false,"itemCommentStatus":0,"showNotPass":false,"vl1":false,"takeDown":0,"itemMute":false,"effectStickers":[],"authorStats":{"followerCount":21600,"followingCount":288,"heart":659400,"heartCount":659400,"videoCount":23,"diggCount":1507},"privateItem":false,"duetEnabled":false,"stitchEnabled":false,"stickersOnItem":[],"isAd":false,"shareEnabled":true,"comments":[]}}}
```

Comment: I solved this thru c# puppeteer.

Answer (score 3):

When requesting the video url, you need to :

- forward the cookies that were set from the initial http call (specifically `tt_webid_v2` but forwarding all cookies will do)
- set the `Referer` HTTP header with the value of the tiktok video url. This value is present in the json result under `seoProps.metaParams.canonicalHref` field.

Note that the initial API call needs the user agent to be set whereas it's not required in the video api call, but I will specify it just in case

The 2 following examples will save the video under file `tiktok.mp4`

An example with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) (storing the cookies in cookies.txt) :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

url="https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/video/@beary730/6976969595781434626"
userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"

read videoUrl referer < <(echo $(curl -c cookies.txt -s "$url" -H "User-Agent: $userAgent" | 
     jq -r '.itemInfo.itemStruct.video.downloadAddr, .seoProps.metaParams.canonicalHref'))

echo "$videoUrl"
echo "$referer"

curl -s "$videoUrl" -H "Referer: $referer" -H "User-Agent: $userAgent" -b cookies.txt -o tiktok.mp4
```

An example in [python](/questions/tagged/python) with [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests):

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/video/@beary730/6976969595781434626"
userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, headers= {
    "User-Agent": userAgent
})
data = r.json()

videoUrl = data["itemInfo"]["itemStruct"]["video"]["downloadAddr"]
referer = data["seoProps"]["metaParams"]["canonicalHref"]

print(videoUrl)
print(referer)

r = s.get(videoUrl, headers= {
    "Referer": referer,
    "User-Agent": userAgent
})
with open('tiktok.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

You won't be able to embed the video url as is on your website, because it needs the cookie and the referer, unless you know how to forge the `tt_webid_v2` cookie but that's not easy since the cookie values seems to depend on `expires` and `signature` url parameters in the video url.

Note that it also works with `playAddr` field as well which also get the video feed data the same way as `downloadAddr`

Comment: HI thanks for ur help but can this be in javascript or jquery? I don't use both of ur examples.